# How do I have two identical json property names assigned to two separated fields

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following Java class [image]

I need to serialize it to json in the following way:

if the list(paymentTransactionReport field) is not null display it values -

```
{ 
"paymentTransactionResponse" : [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

if the list is null I need to display the paymentTransactionReportError in json field with name 'paymentTransactionResponse', as in previous case. Example -

```
{
"paymentTransactionResponse" : {
----
//fields from PaymentTransactionReportError class
----
  }
}
```

How can I do this?preferably without custom serializers.
If use just two annotations @JsonProperty with the same name and JsonInclude.NON_NULL as I did, I have this error: No converter found for return value of type:... Seems to be that is a error happened during serialization because of fields with the same name

Comment: Why you do not want to use custom deserializer? I think it will be a appropriate solution for this.

Comment: @Smile, I didn't say that I do not want to use them :) Just trying to find more easiest way to achieve this.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is, using [@JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html), Try this

```
public class TestDTO {

@JsonIgnore
List<String> paymentTransactionResponse;

@JsonIgnore
String paymentTransactionResponseError;

public List<String> getPaymentTransactionResponse() {
    return paymentTransactionResponse;
}

public void setPaymentTransactionResponse(List<String> paymentTransactionResponse) {
    this.paymentTransactionResponse = paymentTransactionResponse;
}

public String getPaymentTransactionResponseError() {
    return paymentTransactionResponseError;
}

public void setPaymentTransactionResponseError(String paymentTransactionResponseError) {
    this.paymentTransactionResponseError = paymentTransactionResponseError;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getData(){
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if(paymentTransactionResponse != null) {
        map.put("paymentTransactionResponse", paymentTransactionResponse);
    }else {
        map.put("paymentTransactionResponse", paymentTransactionResponseError);
    }
    return map;
}}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.I think I'll use your solution